# How to send array through HTTPservice in Adobe Flex 3

Tags: actionscript-3, http, flex3, service

How to send array in Httpservice in Adobe Flex3

Answer (score 7):

I am not quite sure what you mean by sending an array to a httpservice. If you mean to send an array to a httpservice with the same field name, you can pass an array as field value.

```
var service:HTTPService = new HTTPService();
service.useProxy = true;
service.destination = "myservicet";
service.resultFormat = HTTPService.RESULT_FORMAT_XML;

var fields:Array = ["categories", "organisation"];
var params:Object = new Object();
params.q = "stackoverflow";
params.rows = 0;
params.facet = "true";
params["facet.field"] = fields;
service.send(params);
```

The HTTPService will convert this to the url parameters:

```
facet=true&q=stackoverflow&facet%2Efield=categories&facet%2Efield=organisation&rows=0
```

Hope this helps!

Added for more clarity. When there is only 1 argument in the array, do not pass the fields as an array. For some reason, flex will not send this to the http service

Answer (score 2):

It really depends what is the back end technology you're using. If you're sending it to PHP you could try:

```
var fields:Array = ["categories", "organisation"];
var params:Object = {};
params.q = "stackoverflow";
params.rows = 0;
params.facet = "true";
params["facet.field[]"] = fields;
service.send(params);
```

PHP will generate an array for you.
AFAIR this works fine in Rails as well.

Answer (score 0):

if it is a simple string array, you can [join](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/Array.html#join()) it with a well know separator char, and on the other site, split the string with the same separator back to an array.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a simple array, you could send it as a comma separated string.

> httpService.request = new Object;
>   httpService.request.csv = array.toString();